# Getting a 401 Error when trying to generate a Roku Package File using Bash / Curl

Tags: curl, libcurl, roku

I am trying to programmatically generate and download package files for my Roku channels.
I am using the following script to authenticate to my Roku device but I get a 401 error even though the username and password are correct

```
packageroku() {

uagent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';
ftime = $(($(date + '%s') * 1000));
    if ["$1"] && ["$2"] && ["$3"] && [$ {#1} -lt 32 ]; then
        purl= $(curl--silent--show - error--user - agent "$uagent"--form "app_name=$1"
        --form "passwd=$2"--form "pkg_time=$ftime"--form "mysubmit=Package""http://$3/plugin_package"
        | grep "href" | grep - v "plugin_inspect\|plugin_install" | awk - F 'href="''{ print $2 }'
        | tr '"''\n' | head - n1;);
        wget http: //$3/$purl ;
    else echo - e "Function Description";
    fi

}
```

The error is
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized Username/Password Authentication Failed.
I obtained the following code snippet from the Official Roku Developer Forum http://goo.gl/WZ8fEp
I am not sure if this function is failing  now due to security enhancement that were added to the Roku devices (http://goo.gl/mNUJKK)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is failing due to the added authentication requirement (not really a "security enhancement" IMNSHO) - see http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=70133#p442404 for how to tackle it with curl.